# Cannot access azure key vault secret with python

Tags: python, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I've been able to access azure key vault using oauth rest api through my external web app, but for some reason I am unable to retrieve the secrets from the keys. After long hours of researching I've found out that its possible to do this with powershell and c# but have still yet to find any solution with python.
Anyone know if its possible with python, or is there a way of emulating what powershell is doing through?
Here's the code to retrieve the secret:

```
def getSecret(vault_name, secret_name, secret_version = ''):
    #Get acess token to azure account
    data = { "grant_type" : "client_credentials", 
            "client_id" : 'appidxx', 
            "client_secret" : 'appsecretxx', 
            "resource" : "https://vault.azure.net"
        }
    headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    r = requests.post("https://login.windows.net/{}/oauth2/token".format('my tenant id'), data=data, headers=headers)
    access_token = r.json()['access_token']
    #Get secret from KeyVault
    headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer {}".format(access_token) }
    r = requests.get('https://{}.vault.azure.net/secrets/{}/{}?api-version=2015-06-01'.format(vault_name, secret_name, secret_version), headers=headers)
    result = r.json()
    if 'value' in result.keys():
        return result["value"]
    else: 
        return 'Secret Not Found'

def searchSecret(secret_name, secret_version = ''):
subscription_id = 'subscription id'    
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id= 'appidxx',
        secret= 'appsecretxx',
        tenant= 'tenantidxx'
    )

    kvm_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials,  subscription_id )
    for vault in kvm_client.vaults.list():
        #return when secret found in vault
        secret = getSecret(vault.name, secret_name, secret_version = '')
        if (secret != 'Secret Not Found'):
            return secret
    return 'Secret Not Found'
```

Also I have registered my app in azure portal and granted permissions to my keys and secrets, however i noticed that when granting access to my app through access policy, the "Authorized application" option is locked and i cannot add my app, which may be the root cause of my issue??
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0HBu.png)

Comment: What is the Http status code return? 401?

Comment: Side note: you can use `https://login.microsoftonline.com` instead of `https://login.windows.net`. Though it won't fix the problem. At a glance I could not see anything really wrong with the code. The authorized application thing in Key Vault is not needed. You granted permissions to the service principal.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but why are you using azure-mgmt-keyvault to list the vaults, but direct Rest calls and not azure-keyvault to read the secret?

Comment: thuan, im not getting any http error just not getting access to the secrets. juunas oh ok i really thought that could have been the problem. @laurent i didnt think there was a different way of reading the secrets as im quiet new to azure. i thought azure-keyvault only lists the keys, pls is there a better of doing this?

Comment: You should give your service principal(sp) access your key vault permission. Like this  https://imgur.com/a/mrth1

Comment: Maybe you could check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149806/interacting-with-azure-key-vault-using-python-w-rest-api

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT I have already given access to my service principal shown here https://imgur.com/a/qlVfM. And regarding that answer, ive tried that method but still returning same result: ##### vaultname#####
{u'error': {u'message': u'Secret not found: vaultname/secretid', u'code': u'SecretNotFound'}}

Comment: @flowstack What is the result do you get? If possible, could you show it as a screenshot? I test you code in my lab, it works for me.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Oh thats quiet strange, so it displays your secret as in the actual secret not secret name?? maybe its because i created my secrets before creating my app and adding to service principal? i'll try creating a new key and secret and see if that will work. here is my error https://imgur.com/a/CRCzV. it errors 6 times because i've got 6 keys

Comment: I test you code by using `getSecret('shui','shui02','b89f7498e8c64b6c9365e0eda55b4b5b')`.  This is my test result https://imgur.com/a/DsqyN

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems you give a wrong secret version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, you should give your service principal access your key vault permission. Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuywL.jpg.

I test your code by using `getSecret('shui','shui02','b89f7498e8c64b6c9365e0eda55b4b5b')`, it works for me.

```
import requests
def getSecret(vault_name, secret_name, secret_version = ''):
    #Get acess token to azure account
    data = { "grant_type" : "client_credentials", 
            "client_id" : '*******', 
            "client_secret" : '*******', 
            "resource" : "https://vault.azure.net"
        }
    headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    r = requests.post("https://login.windows.net/{}/oauth2/token".format('*******'), data=data, headers=headers)
    access_token = r.json()['access_token']
    #Get secret from KeyVault
    headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer {}".format(access_token) }
    r = requests.get('https://{}.vault.azure.net/secrets/{}/{}?api-version=2015-06-01'.format(vault_name, secret_name, secret_version), headers=headers)
    print r
    result = r.json()
    if 'value' in result.keys():
        return result["value"]
    else: 
        return 'Secret Not Found'
getSecret('shui','shui02','b89f7498e8c64b6c9365e0eda55b4b5b')
```

Comment: I just retested it and it turns out i was indeed using the wrong secret version. I read somewhere during my research that it wasn't really important and that it could be left blank which turns is obviously false. Anyways ive used the correct version now which is the secret id and it works. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Hi another thing, how can i get the list of secret names/versions without hard-coding them pls? like getting the list of key names using vault.name

Comment: @flowstack It is possible, you also could use Key Vault API. `GET {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/versions?api-version=2016-10-01` See this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecretversions/getsecretversions

Comment: @flowstack If you want to get all secrets in your keyvault, you should use `GET {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets?api-version=2016-10-01`, see this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecrets/getsecrets

Comment: @shui thats what i did in the end. I used the key vault API (which is what i should have used in the beginning) to pull the secret names and versions then used GET https://{}.vault.azure.net/secrets/{}/{}?api-version=2016-10-01 to get the secrets. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access secrets more easily using the Azure SDK, there are new packages for working with Key Vault in Python that replace `azure-keyvault`:

- [azure-keyvault-certificates](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-certificates/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-certificates/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-keys](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/migration_guide.md)

[azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) is also the package that should be used with these for authentication.

Documentation for working with the secrets library can be found on the [azure-sdk-for-python GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/README.md), and here's a sample for retrieving secrets as you were doing:

```python
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id = "subscription id"

def getSecret(vault_url, secret_name, secret_version=None):
    client = SecretClient(vault_url, credential)
    # list the secrets in the vault
    secret_properties = client.list_properties_of_secrets()
    for secret_property in secret_properties:
        if secret_property.name == secret_name:
            # get secret from Key Vault
            return client.get_secret(secret_name, secret_version)
    return "Secret Not Found"

def searchSecret(secret_name, secret_version=None):
    kvm_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
    for vault in kvm_client.vaults.list():
        # return when secret found in vault
        secret = getSecret(vault.properties.vault_uri, secret_name, secret_version)
        if secret != "Secret Not Found":
            return secret
    return "Secret Not Found"
```

You can provide the same credentials that you used for `ServicePrincipalCredentials` by setting environment variables corresponding to the `client_id`, `secret`, and `tenant`:

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID="appidxx"
export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="appsecretxx"
export AZURE_TENANT_ID="tenantidxx"
```

(I work on the Azure SDK in Python)